# Woocommerce Storefront template-tags.php changes to storefront_cart_link() not possible

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am using WordPress 4.3.1, Woocommerce 2.4.7 and the theme storefront 1.5.1.

I want to change the "site-header-cart" in the header, that displays the current price of the cart along the amount of items in the cart, to only show the number of items:

```
<span class="amount">463,33&nbsp;€</span>
<span class="count">7 items</span>
```

Should be:

```
<span class="count">7</span>
```

Whenever I make changes to template-tags.php only changes outside of the

```
<a class="cart-contents" ...>
...
</a>
```

are being displayed. Whenever I try to change something inside the href the unchanged original will show up:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_cart_link' ) ) {
    function storefront_cart_link() {
        ?>
            <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
                <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'storefront' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?></span>
            </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Whats going on, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Same here. All I know for now is that 1) When Javascript is disabled you see the changes in the template as expected; 2) There is an item in sessionStorage that holds the original template, which replaces the template you set.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the sessionStorage item? In the console: sessionStorage.removeItem('wc_fragments')

Answer (score 10):

I had the same Issue. The fact is, that you have to make a operation on the cart like add a item or empty the cart to get your changes visible. Another option is clearing the sessionStorage like Loque described.

**1. Add code to your custom functions.php**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_cart_link' ) ) {
    function storefront_cart_link() {
        ?>
            <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
                <span class="count"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();?></span>
            </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

**2. Do a operation on the cart or clear the sessionStorage in Console:**

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('wc_fragments')
```

**3. Refresh your Browser --> very Important**

Before:

```
<span class="count">1 items</span>
```

After:

```
<span class="count">1</span>
```

Comment: Step 2 didn't work for me because the session storage key name had a hash at the end of it, so I just had to open browser's dev tools > Application tab > Session Storage and delete it manually. But yeah, forgetting that step can be maddening.

Comment: So I do this in 2 steps: 1) type `sessionStorage` in the console and get a list of items; 2) find an item that starts with `wc_fragments_` and type `sessionStorage.removeItem('<name of this item>').`